# Make taxonomy terms appear in the order they were made

Tags: taxonomy, terms

IS it possible to make taxonomy terms appear in the order they were made, in the backend?

They keep appearing in alphabetical order. I tried using `sort` but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is my code for creating custom taxonomies:

```
$taxonomies['size'] = array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'query_var' => 'size',
            'sort' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'size',
            ),
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Size',
                'singular_name' => 'Size',
                'update_item' => 'Update Color',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Size',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add Size',
                'new_item_name' => 'Add New Size',
                'all_items' => 'All Sizes',
                'search_items' => 'Search Sizes',
                'popular_items' => 'Popular Sizes',
                'popular_items_with_comments' => 'Separate sizes with commas',
                'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or remove sizes',
                'choose_from_most_used' => 'Choose from most used sizes'
            )
        );
```

Comment: There is no _general setting_ for this. So, where exactly do you want to have this feature? On the _All Posts_ page (i.e., `edit.php`)? When editing an individual post (i.e., `post.php`)? When creating a new post (i.e., `post-new.php`)? Something other than that?

Comment: In the backend, where I add the terms to posts. You know how they are listed below the taxonomy name? I wanted them to be listed there in the order they were made.

Comment: I've dealt a similar problem. The solution was to connect a custom post with a term from the custom taxonomy. That way each term can have a date to be sorted.